# Python 3.2: can't import sqlite3 module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've just installed python 3.2.2 on ubuntu 10.04.3 (following all instraction from readme file) and tried to import sqlite3 module - the result:

```
No module named _sqlite3
```

Then I've looked into lib-dynload directory and there is **no file _sqlite3.so** (but it is in python 2.6).

How to fix this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: There is probably different package for Python 3 SQlite. Python 2 and Python 3 libraries are incompatible.

Comment: Just to clarify - you compiled the source code instead of pulling it from the repository?

Comment: Installing process: 1) `./configure` 2) `make` 3) `make test` 4) `sudo make install`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you installed from source, you need to install the development libraries for sqlite3.

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

You probably also want to install `libreadline-dev` and `libssl-dev`.

Comment: Can I do that after installing Python or I need to reinstall it?

Comment: You will need to go the source directory and re-run make and make install.

Comment: @LennartRegebro: In this case, the development libraries for sqlite3 (and other modules like readline, ssl, etc.) need to be installed before compiling Python from source. The C source code for the Python sqlite module is included with Python's source; however it requires the presence of sqlite3's development file to compile. It is not a separate library but part of Python.

Comment: @casevh: You are right, I wasn't reading carefully and answered the wrong thing. :-)

Answer (score 8):

**Download python 3.3.2** http://www.python.org/getit/

The `development libraries` for sqlite3 (and other modules like readline, ssl, etc.) `need to be installed before compiling Python from source.` The C source code for the Python sqlite module is included with Python's source; however it requires the presence of sqlite3's development file to compile. It is not a separate library but part of Python.

If you installed from source, you need to install the development libraries for sqlite3.

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

**What are the packages/libraries I should install before compiling Python from source?**
https://askubuntu.com/questions/21547/what-are-the-packages-libraries-i-should-install-before-compiling-python-from-so

```
sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

List of common dev environments ...

```
build-essential (obviously)
libz-dev        (also pretty common and essential)
libreadline-dev (or the Python prompt is crap)
libncursesw5-dev
libssl-dev
libgdbm-dev
libsqlite3-dev
libbz2-dev
liblzma-dev
tk-dev
libdb-dev
libncursesw5-dev
libreadline5-dev
libssl-dev
libgdbm-dev
libc6-dev
```

**Install Python**

```
tar xf Python-3.3.2.tar.xz
./configure
make
sudo make all install
```

Answer (score 1):

My Python **3.4.1** had the same problem on **ubuntu 12.04**, when I use [SQLAlchemy library](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/cca4d8fc73df042e938447ec0bc990be28c4fb11/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/sqlite/pysqlite.py#L337). The reason was as what other people related to this question suggested, my system did not have the development package installed before I compiled and installed python 3.4.1. So I did:

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

And then went to my extracted python source and did re-compliation as the steps described in the answers for this question. Then I was able to:

```
Python 3.4.1 (default)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite3
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

sqlite3 is not part of the "python" package, you can install it from 
port: databases/py-sqlite3. As there's no specific python3 versions of 
that ports you need to set PYTHON_VERSION=python3.5 before building. 
Both 2.x and 3.x versions of package can coexist peacefully.

make -C /usr/ports/databases/py-sqlite3 PYTHON_VERSION=3.5 install